# Docusign console view request is giving "errorCode": "INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE"

Tags: docusignapi

I have following request sent to docusign to get the console view of the document, but I'm getting "INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE"

All informations below are arbitrary because of privacy concern. I want to know if the request is correct.

```
{ method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/+' accountId '+/views/console',
  body: '{"envelopeId":"a40b28fa-a89f-49e0-af03-2342334234"}', 
  headers: 
   { 'X-DocuSign-Authentication': '{"Username":username,"Password":password,"IntegratorKey":"INTKEY-sjdfhf876-1cf4-4776-aac1-786767676"}',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'content-length': '58' } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro this and my request was successful. The only difference between my invocation and yours was the quotes around 'application/json'. Remove the quotes.